# can't open site with docker-compose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker-compose

everybody. I have docker-compose with nodejs.

```
web:
...
  ports:
    - "3030:3000"
 ....
```

app.js:

```
    ...
server.listen(8000, function(){
   console.log('test');
});
```

we can see port is 8000.

I do `docker-compose up`
and terminal has 'test'

But http://MY_IP:8000 hasn't "Can not access site"

I do start with `docker-compose run web npm start` server started, but i get
that error too.

How start nodejs with docker-compose ?

P.S.:
If i install npm install WITHOUT docker-compose command. I have not this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `docker-compose.yml` you are saying to bind the port `3030` to your host and `3000` in your container.

The config in your `docker-compose.yml` should be:

```
web:
...
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
...
```

Moreover I think you should also bind your app inside the container to `0.0.0.0` to ease development, additional set-up can be done once moving to production. `app.js`:

```
server.listen('8000', '0.0.0.0', function(){
  console.log('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't access to http://YOUR_IP:8000 because you didn't bind container port (8000) to host port (8000). Add this to your `docker-compose.yml`.

```
web:
...
  ports:
    - "3030:3000"
    - "8000:8000"
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change  - "3030:3000" to  - "8000:8000" in your docker-compose.yml file

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this flag: `--host=0.0.0.0`

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    container_name: sdp
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules 
    command: sls offline --host=0.0.0.0
```